# HTML 5 Linking/Masking <input type='file'> to an <a>

Tags: javascript, css, html, api

If the title confuses you; what's the most elegant way to mask the difficult `<input type='file'/>` to a friendly `<a/>` so when the `<a>` is selected, the file explorer is prompted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simulate a click with jQuery like this.

```
<input type='file' id="myInput"/>
    <a href="#" id="myAnchor">Launch File Upload</a>
```

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

```
$("#myAnchor").click(function () {

    $("#myInput").trigger('click');

});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swordfish0321/aZ8eL/)
    ​

Comment: Just tested this in Firefox, Chrome, Opera and IE10 and it works.  I haven't seen able to test it with (IETester)[http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage] for earlier Internet Explorers, but that might be a JSFiddle thing.

Comment: Very clean and short, I like it. Thank you!